# List won't center horizontally

Tags: html, css, list, position, center

Does any have a suggestion to why this list won't display AND center horizontally.

When the li items actually displays inline, I'm sure the centering follows...

http://jsfiddle.net/yLHaB/

THANKS

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<div class="navtable">
<ul id="nav1">
    <li><img src="images/kranznav2.png" alt="kranz"/><a href="index.php">COMPETE</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnav2.png" alt="thumb"/><a href="score.php">SCORE</a></li>
    <div id="logolist"><li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logorz.png" width="175em" /></a></li></div>
    <li><img src="images/bagnav2.png" alt="bag"/><a href="index.php">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/morenav2.png" alt="more"/><a href="index.php">MORE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    position:relative;
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    height:0.2em:
    overflow:visible;
    margin-top:-2em;
    font-family:Cusmyrb;
    font-size:75%;

}

#logolist {
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:2em;
    width:250px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-7%;

}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#343234;
    text-decoration:none;


}

.navtable {
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
}

ul#nav1 {

    min-width:700px;
    list-style:none;
    padding-top:20px;
}

ul#nav1 li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Your `div` wrapping a `li` isn't valid HTML. You should run your site through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/ real quick.

Comment: For starters, put `display: inline` on the `ul` not the `li`.  Also, you don't need the `ul` in front of `#nav`.  Id's should be unique, so you don't need to qualify it.  Then float the `li`'s to the left.  And get rid of the `div` inside the `ul`, that's illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this:

```
.navtable {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 90px;
}
```

You need to set a fixed width to your nav, this example will work.

Comment: If you check the fiddle, adding a width to .navtable doesn't display it horizontally...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `ul#nav1` to be centered you just need to add `margin: 0 auto;` at it.

at fiddle you wont see this working since your wrapper `div#nav` is set to get width 100%, if you set it to `2000px` it should show it properly.

Hope this helps :)